# Want to know the base level (not the basics) architecture of the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am having a good knowledge of JavaScript, I have a passion to know more and in-depth about it. So I am start searching for the base or structural level  and also various concept like event delegate, event bubbling etc. is there is any resource for it?

Comment: Event delegation and event bubbling are DOM concepts, not JavaScript concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my favorite resources is Douglas Crockford's series of videos on Javascript: http://javascript.crockford.com/

He gives you a whole history lesson wrapped up into practical usage that explains the how and why the system works. Beyond that, check out the resources that John Resig has available on his blog (the creator of JQuery, a very popular Javascript library): http://ejohn.org/blog/

This is a fun one after you have gone through the Crockford videos: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

If you can understand what both Crockford and Resig discuss, you'll be able to handle just about any problem JS can throw at you.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two.

[Douglas Crockford's javascript page](http://javascript.crockford.com/) is full of awesome knowledge pearls about the language (both basics and advanced stuff).

The [Secrets of the Javascript Ninja](http://jsninja.com/) book is an advanced resource. It's written by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/), the guy bejind [jquery](http://jquery.com/). It's still not out, but if you pre-buy it you have access to the beta editions (a new one popped out 2 weeks ago)

Answer (score 0):

I think [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/) has a very good introduction to events:

- [Introducation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)
- [Event Order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)
- [Early event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html)
- [Traditional event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)
- [Advanced event registration models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)
- [Event properties](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)
- [Event compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html)

Then of course there is [MDC JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) and various books such as

- [High Performance JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680279X)
- [JavaScript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752)

Comment: Yeah, already i am using this MDC and JavaScript Patterns (Apress Edition) Thanks For your Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To really get stuck into the architecture of javascript you should have a good thorough read of the [Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

The specification will let you have a better understanding of the internals of JavaScript and gives an insight into how things work under the hood. You may also get a feeling for what non-standard parts of javascript you've been accidentally using.

Another route to getting a better understanding would be to read well known and (hopefully) well structured open source [libraries](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/deconstructed/).

Reading such libraries is a great way to learn javascript design patterns and how to utilise various parts to the maximum effect.

A third, (and significantly more advance) option would be to read the open source implementation of [chrome](http://code.google.com/chromium/).

This would give you an understanding of the low level implentation of javascript. You know exactly what the interpreter is doing with your code under the hood.

If your interested in the DOM more then JavaScript itself you can always read the HTML5 [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html)

Comment: Thanks Raynos Great Resource Man.